# How to Check Repeated Schedule Exists Before Adding New Schedule

Tags: php, sql-server, schedule

I am trying to build schedule system for classes

A Schedule have a repeated type like Daily, Weekly, Monthly.

Now i am unable to check the new schedule adding is already exists/ in between another schedule etc.,

The fields of my form are

```
Class ID, 
Time [Day Schedule Time], 
Start [When Schedule Starts], 
End [When will Schedule Ends], 
Repeat [Daily, Weekly, Monthly]
```

Mean while I try this, But it doesn't work for Weekly, Monthly and Yearly

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `schedule` 
WHERE  '2015-04-09 06:17:17' <= startdt
AND  '2015-04-10 06:17:17' >= enddt
AND TYPE =  'daily'
AND (
(
'03:07:00' NOT 
BETWEEN TIME
AND endtime
)
AND (
'04:14:00' NOT 
BETWEEN TIME
AND endtime
)
AND (
TIME NOT 
BETWEEN  '04:07:00'
AND  '04:07:00'
)
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: In what way are you unable to check? How are you doing so? Are you writing some SQL to make this check and pasting it into your database client, or do you want to do this with PHP?

Comment: i want do this with SQL SERVER, Or PHP logic will also be helpful to me

Comment: OK, your edit is a good start - we can now see what you are working on. However, this is the `daily` query that presumably works - can we see a non-working one too? In what way does it "not work"? Have you tried taking out `WHERE` clauses to see which one is causing it to fail?

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify this please? When you create a new schedule are you creating all the repeat entries, and you're trying to check there will be no conflicts before adding another repeat schedule?

I assume Start equates to a date, and your classes are fixed time slots ie 1 hour? So your unpacked data from schedule might look like this? (Simplified with some normalisation)

**CalendarEntries**
ScheduleID
ClassroomID
Date
StartTime  (*Fixed duration assumed - If not, add an end time*)

The above being populated once a schedule is ok'd, and would hold all classrooms, dates and times?

If you were going to create a new schedule you might generate all your proposed new entries into a temporary table with the same structure then:

```
...
IF EXISTS (
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM #PlannedEntries A
INNER JOIN CalendarEntries B
ON A.Date = B.Date
AND A.ClassroomID = B.ClassroomID
AND ( 
A.StartTime BETWEEN B.StartTime AND DATEADD(MIN,@LessonDuration,B.StartTime)
      OR 
DATEADD(MIN,@LessonDuration,A.StartTime) BETWEEN B.StartTime AND DATEADD(MIN,@LessonDuration,B.StartTime)
     OR
(A.StartTime < B.StartTime AND DATEADD(MIN,@LessonDuration,A.StartTime) > DATEADD(MIN,@LessonDuration,B.StartTime) 

)
   PRINT 'Schedule Conflict'
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'Schedule Added'
   INSERT INTO CalendarEntries SELECT * FROM #PlannedEntries 
END
```

You'll want to consider the subjects and resources ie staff too presumably.
Add some clarification and I'll see if I can point you in the right direction when I'm back on ;)

Note - this is messy. I'd seperate start and end time and you can simplify the above. It's also far simpler if you have a "slot" system rather than time based if it's lessons. There are also better ways to structure it - let me know if this is the sort of problem you're up against and I'll refine it.

Comment: It's generally preferred that clarification questions are asked in comments, as there is a risk that if an OP does not reply, an answer is permanently stuck containing more questions than help. I accept however you cannot yet comment on posts directly - nearly there! The OP may wish to do this in PHP, and _personally_ I'd wait until they demonstrated more of an effort. Nevertheless, this looks helpful.